# UIAlertView clickedButtonAtIndex EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, uialertview, exc-bad-access

I currently have a UIAlertView being shown with two option buttons. When the user presses one of the buttons, I would like a method (in the same object) to be called that would then retrieve a file from the web.

I can call the method fine and can call NSLog(), but as soon as I come to use any object variables, I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

My first thought was it could be a threading issue, so thought calling NSNotificationCenter might solve it, but that too ends in the same error.

Below is the code I've got at the moment. I have tried a few different things (some are commented out) to no avail. The 'dbURL' object is a property of the class. (**Edit**: below code is not complete)

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

//If database update
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"newdb" object:self]; //EXC_BAD_ACCESS happens here

if ([alertView.title isEqualToString: @"Database Update"]){
    switch (buttonIndex) {
        case 0:
            //[self getNewDatabase];
            //[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(getNewDatabase) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
            //[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(getNewDatabase) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"newdb" object:self];
            break;




// Get a new database file from the server
- (void)getNewDatabase{


    NSLog(@"in database: %@", dbURL);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you use more than one UIAlertView instance in the same class?

Comment: Yes, but they are not interfering with each other.

Comment: I am curious, why are you using `(alertView.title == @"Database Update")`? As Matteo Alessani posted, this comparison won't work as expected. And can you enable NSZombieEnabled and dump the error on your console? The stacktrace would also be helpful.

Comment: **SOLVED** used NSZombieEnabled to find the issue; an object variable was not being retained properly that was then being called in the getNewDatabase method. Thank you Nick Weaver!  (will reply with a proper answer in 8 hours lol!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was an object I was calling as not being retained properly and therefore the reference was lost, resulting in an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error

Thanks to Nick Weaver. Using the **NSZombieEnabled** argument in the build options helped to identify the rogue reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare NSString with == . You need to use **isEqualToString**:

```
[alertView.title isEqualToString:@"Database Update"]
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the source of the problem. Moving the Notification center call to outside the IF statement still results in BAD_ACCESS

Comment: You are wrong my friend... his error is came inside the block so it checks the value successfully...

Comment: yes... I thought that if the check fail, maybe you do something with the wrong object